# Strange behavior of Page View Controller on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, iphone-6, pagecontrol

I trying to implement page view controller with three pages. I already did it, it works very well on iPhones with 3.5- and 4-inch displays, but something wrong happens with 4.7- and 5.5-inch displays.

I found that hiding of standard Page Control of UIPageViewController is reason of this bug: when page control gets hidden the view of UIPageVC changes his height (+ height of Page Control View).

My page content view controllers has constraints for background image view to fit to all sizes.

This is first page:
[image: This is first page]

This is second page:
[image: This is second page]

This is third page, ok, we've reached last page:
[image: This is third page]

But look what happens when we return to the second page (View of page content controller fully moved at few pixels to the left):
[image: This is again second page]

Swipe to the first page - the same result:
[image: This is again first page]

**BUT!** Look what we have when after the first page we go to the second page! Now view of page content controller at the right position by x:
[image: This is second page]

Go to the last page:
[image: This is the last page]

Let's come back to the second page! Holy ****! View gets moved by something again:
[image: This is the second page]

Go to the first page, all in the 'right' (**BAD**) positions:
[image: This is the first page]

Go back to the second page from first page. All in the good and right positions:
[image: This is the second page]

So, my question is what is going on with this UIPageViewController? I thought that my constraints gets broken but I have nothing in my logs about it, in storyboard there are no error related to constraints.

When I use two methods "presentationCountForPageViewController:, presentationIndexForPageViewController:" all is good but above the button appears a white line of height equal to Page Control view's height (so, I need to hide it by erasing two methods listed above).

Thanks in advance for you future suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it! But not by the right way because it is iOS-side bug.

So, when you trying to hide Page Control View of your UIPageViewController the private 'pageSpacing' property gets broken on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus by unexpected reason. It is hard to see and understand it from views. In my case for iPhone 6 InterPageSpacing property has been decreased by 4 and for iPhone 6 Plus - by 6 values. So, if you'll try to to set pageSpacing property for iPhone 4 or 5 you'll see a white line between pages but on 6 and 6 Plus this line disappears and view of second controller moves to few pixels left.

For now I just set different values for UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey while initialize my UIPageViewController:

```
- (id)initWithTransitionStyle:(UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle)style navigationOrientation:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation)navigationOrientation options:(NSDictionary *)options
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    NSNumber *pageSpacing =
    IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS
    ? @(0)
    : IS_IPHONE_5
    ? @(0)
    : IS_IPHONE_6
    ? @(4)
    : @(6);

    [dictionary setValue:pageSpacing forKey:UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey];

    self = [super initWithTransitionStyle:style navigationOrientation:navigationOrientation options:dictionary];
    return self;
}
```

Yes, fix is dirty but I didn't find another way to fix it, especially as it is bug of Apple.

Comment: wow! it's been 2 years and now I'm experience this in iphone 5c, ios 10.3. How did you debug and get the broken `pageSpacing` value? I tried debug with capture screen, the debugger shows everything is in correct position...

Comment: @Eddie, I already forgot it. May be it was just an empirical way :)
I suggest you to fully recreate the view controller in the storyboard and compile it with full clean. May be it will help you.